# Does the Macbook (Early 2016) support Wake up from standby through an alarm or at a scheduled time?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, windows, sleep-wake

I am looking for an option to wake the Macbook at a given time or even date (if possible).
Is there such an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System Prefs > Energy Saver > Schedule...

You can set sleep/reboot/shutdown or wake times.
There's no default option for a specific date, but there are options for day, weekdays, weekend etc.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there something that combines this option with an alarm ?

Comment: That would be a separate question really, but you can do it with Calendar

Comment: thank you. It was part of the question though.

Comment: Calendar can't wake it, only provide your alarm after it's awake.